# How to parse json file in new intent with volley

Tags: android, json, android-intent, android-volley, android-json

I am working on an android app and I need to get some data from the internet like the name and link, I watched some tutorials on how to use volley to parse a JSON file and get my data from the internet which worked but now I want to display some data when a new intent is created but it doesn't seem to work my Textview remains unchanged, This is the code:

```
    public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private String radioName;
    private TextView radionametxt;
    private String radioLink;
    private TextView radiolinktxt;
    private String urlJsonArry;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

        Intent i = getIntent();
        final String radioname = i.getStringExtra("radioname");
        setTitle(radioname);

        urlJsonArry = "https://api.myjson.com/bins/1f7y96";

        JsonArrayRequest req = new JsonArrayRequest(urlJsonArry,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

                        try {
                            // Parsing json array response
                            // loop through each json object
                            //jsonResponse = "";
                            for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {

                                JSONObject radio = (JSONObject) response
                                        .get(i);

                               // String name = radio.getString("name");
                               // String link = radio.getString("email");

                                //radioName = name;
                               // radioLink = link;

                                radioName = radio.getString("name");
                                radioLink = radio.getString("email");

                            }
                            radionametxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
                            radionametxt.setText(radioName);

                            radiolinktxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.link);
                            radiolinktxt.append(radioLink);


                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Error: " + e.getMessage(),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }


                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.d("Error", "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.radline.radapp.radapp.Main2Activity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="name"
    android:textSize="40sp"
    tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
    android:layout_marginTop="62dp"
    tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/link"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/link" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/link"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="link"
    android:textSize="40sp"
    tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
    tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1"
    android:layout_marginStart="108dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="108dp"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.321" />
```

Json code

```
    [
  {
    "name": "radone",
    "link": "ravi8x@gmail.com"
  }
]
```

Comment: Declare  radionametxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
 out of response as it always initialise new one.

Comment: @RohanLodhi I just answered the question, thank you. One major mistake i made was forgetting to add the code for request queue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fetched JsonObject instead of JsonArray and remember to add the code for request queue which I forgot before so:

```
package com.radline.radapp.radapp;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.Request.Method;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.VolleyLog;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private String radioName;
    private TextView radionametxt;
    private String radioLink;
    private TextView radiolinktxt;
    private String urlJsonArry;
    private String urlJsonObj;
    private RequestQueue requestQueue;
    private static String TAG = Main2Activity.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

        Intent i = getIntent();
        final String radioname = i.getStringExtra("radioname");
        setTitle(radioname);


        radionametxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
        radiolinktxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.link);
        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        urlJsonObj = "https://api.myjson.com/bins/t92sy";


        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Method.GET,
                urlJsonObj, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                Log.d(TAG, response.toString());

                try {
                    // Parsing json object response
                    // response will be a json object
                    radioName = response.getString("name");
                    radioLink = response.getString("audiolink");


                    radionametxt.setText(radioName);
                    radiolinktxt.setText(radioLink);


                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Error: " + e.getMessage(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
               // hidepDialog();
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                // hide the progress dialog
               // hidepDialog();
            }
        });

        // Adding request to request queue
        requestQueue.add(jsonObjReq);

    }
}
```

also changed the xml to :

```
 {
  "name": "Cyntric Station",
  "audiolink": "http://111.223.51.8:8000",
  "picturelink": "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/01/04/08/04/people-3060107_960_720.jpg",
  "motto": "Your number 1 online radio station"
}
```